# Google Cloud Endpoints iOS client library: 'duplicate symbols error'

Tags: ios, xcode, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Google App Engine server which uses Google Cloud Endpoints v1. I generated the iOS client library as per these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/calling-from-ios#compiling_the_client_library_generator_and_generating_your_library

However when importing the client library files to Xcode, I get multiple 'duplicate symbols' errors when running Build. How can I fix these?

Comment: Can you add more details on what the duplicate symbols are? Do they correspond to methods in your API or resource types?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the file ending with _Sources.m.
This did the trick for me.